# using arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server to publish to portal

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-portal

[image]

I'm using `arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server()` to publish SD files to a server that is federated with portal.  Using this [ESRI Documentaion](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00540000001p000000) I am able to publish the service to a specific folder on my server with the arguments  `in_folder_type="XXX", in_folder="xxx"` Since my server is federated with portal those services are automatically shared with `Portal` which is what I want.  However I would like like the services to appear in a specific folder as I did with server.  I do not see a control to do this.  Is this possible?

---

I attached an image of an example structure a service that is published to the server needs to be told to reside in a certain folder in portal. Not the root directory of portal.

Comment: a specific folder in portal? Like a group?

Comment: No, a folder. X service hosted on server goes in y folder in portal..The visibility of Y folder is  managed though groups and user controls within Portal.

Comment: Do you have 10.3? Take a look at the [MXD to WebMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/server-toolbox/mxd-to-webmap.htm) tool. We implemented folder that does what you want there (you can look at the tool code). Without digging in, I'm pretty sure you'll need to manually move the item after publishing it (like we did)...

Comment: While I did not know about `MXDToWebMap_server` that tool is for maps, my question is service specific. And yes I have 10.3.1

Comment: The tool makes SDs, uploads them, and turns them into a featureservice to build the map off of. Regardless, I 99% sure that UploadService tool _only_ uses Folder in the context of **server**, not Portal. Looking at the REST API, theres no "folder" on addItem, so you'll need to call [MoveItem](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Move_Item/02r300000078000000/) after you've upload your SD.

Comment: @KHibma that's an answer^

Comment: @risail do you use arcmap or arcgis pro?

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @KHibma:

> Take a look at the [MXD to
>   WebMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/server-toolbox/mxd-to-webmap.htm)
>   tool. We implemented folder that does what you want there (you can
>   look at the tool code). Without digging in, I'm pretty sure you'll
>   need to manually move the item after publishing it (like we did)...

---

> The tool makes SDs, uploads them, and turns them into a featureservice
>   to build the map off of. Regardless, I 99% sure that UploadService
>   tool *only* uses Folder in the context of **server**, not Portal.
>   Looking at the REST API, theres no "folder" on addItem, so you'll need
>   to call
>   [MoveItem](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Move_Item/02r300000078000000/)
>   after you've upload your SD.